# How to replace graph communities with the associated bar charts?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, code-request

The following code generates a community graph and a set of bar charts, each one of which corresponds to a community.

```
ClearAll[vl, el, ew, names, community, g];

el = {"str4" \[DirectedEdge] "scst", "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "srtl", 
   "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "shot", "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "str4", 
   "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "ma8", "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "str3", 
   "sfin" \[DirectedEdge] "shot", "sfin" \[DirectedEdge] "ma6"};
vl = VertexList[el];
ew = {0.01313, 0.0139, 0.0188, 0.01145, 0.01842, 0.01786, 0.0137, 
   0.01561};
names = {
   "agr: Agriculture, hunting, forestry, fishing", 
   "min: Mining and quarrying", "ma1: Food, beverages, tobacco", 
   "ma2: Textiles, textile products", 
   "ma3:   Leather, leather products, footwear", 
   "ma4: Wood & products of wood and cork", 
   "ma5: Pulp, paper, paper products, printing, publishing", 
   "ma6: Coke, refined petroleum, nuclear fuel", 
   "ma7: Chemicals & chemical products", 
   "ma8: Rubber-plastics products", 
   "ma9: Other non-metallic mineral products", 
   "ma10: Manufacture of basic metals", 
   "ma11: Machinery-equipment n.e.c", "ma12: Electrical equipment", 
   "ma13: Transport equipment", "ma14: Manufacturing, nec; recycling",
    "segw: Electricity, gas, water supply", "scst: Construction", 
   "ma15: Sale-maintenance; repair-install. of mach. equip.", 
   "swhl: Wholesale trade, except motor vehicles", 
   "srtl: Retail trade, except of motor vehicles", 
   "shot: Hotels & restaurants", "str1: Inland transport", 
   "str2: Water transport", "str3: Air transport", 
   "str4: Other supporting-transport act. of travel agencies", 
   "stel: Post & telecommunications", 
   "sfin: Financial intermediation", "sest: Real estate activities", 
   "sbus: Renting of M&Eq and other business activities", 
   "sadm: Public adm.-defence;compulsory social security", 
   "sedu: Education", "shlt: Human health-social work", 
   "soth: Other community, social & personal services"
   };

g = Graph[vl, el, VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeWeight -> ew];

community = FindGraphCommunities[g];
CommunityGraphPlot[g]
vName = Lookup[Flatten@community]@
   MapApply[Rule]@
    Map[StringTrim@*StringDelete["\n" | "  "]]@
     StringSplit[names, ": "];
vRule = Thread[Flatten[community] -> vName];

value = {12, 34, 51, 80, 45, 68, 34, 56, 73};
valueAdded = Thread[vl -> value];

barCharts = 
 BarChart[# /. valueAdded, ChartLabels -> {None, #}] & /@ community
```

[image]

I simply want to replace three bar charts with three communities in such a way as to best show the distribution of the edges in a circular embedding format. I have extracted the sets of within-community and between-community edges as follows (by @kglr):

```
ClearAll[cToCedges, edgesBetweenCommunities]
cToCedges = Module[
    {vToC = 
      Association[
       Join @@ MapIndexed[Thread[# -> #2[[1]]] &]@
         FindGraphCommunities[#]]}, 
    KeySort@GroupBy[EdgeList@#, 
      Sort[vToC /@ 
      VertexList[{#}]] &]] &; (* Community-to-Community edges *)
edgesBetweenCommunities = 
  KeySelect[Unequal @@ # &]@*
   cToCedges;  (* edges between communities *)
   
    TableForm[
  PadRight[{{(cToCedges@g)[[1]], (cToCedges@g)[[4]], (cToCedges@g)[[5]],Flatten@Table[edgesBetweenCommunities[g][[i]], {i, Length[edgesBetweenCommunities[g]]}]}}], 
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"\nC1", "\nC2", "\nC3", 
     "Edges between\ncommunities"}}
  ] /. {0 -> _}
```

[image]

These edges should be mapped onto the bar charts (i.e., communities) to construct a community graph with bar charts.

**Update**

Here is the picture of the desired output:

[image]

The arrows originating from a community should take the color of that community. For example, the arrows originating from `community 2` should be `green`, the arrows originating from `community 1` should be `blue` and so on. In my exercises, the number of communities varies, and hence, the figure should be flexible to automatically adjust to the number of communities in a graph.

Comment: could you add a hand-drawn sketch of desired output?

Comment: @kglr: I will do that in a moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, two custom functions to be used as option settings for `EdgeShapeFunction` and `VertexShapeFunction`:

```
ClearAll[circleToCoords, poincareESF, VSF]

circleToCoords[Circle[ctr_, rad_, {a1_, a2_}]] := 
  Module[{al = Subdivide[a1, a2, 50]}, 
   (ctr + rad {Cos[#1], Sin[#1]} &) /@ al];

poincareESF = Module[{}, GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart;
  ReplaceAll[c_Circle :> Arrow@circleToCoords[c]]@
   GraphComputation`GraphChartDump`geo[0.99 First @ #, 0.99 Last @ #, 
     "segment"]] &;

VSF[shape_ : "Bar"][clr_, lbl_, val_, vcount_, gap_ : .2, fs_ : .05] :=
  Module[{seg, angle = ArcTan @@ #,
     width = (1 - gap) 2 Pi /(1 + vcount),
     off = If[0 < ArcTan @@ # < Pi, 1, -1],
     tr = If[shape == "Bar", TranslationTransform[val #], Map[(1 + val) # &]]},
    seg = {Cos @ #, Sin @ #} & /@ 
      Subdivide[angle - width/2, angle + width/2, 50];
    {clr, 
     Text[Style[lbl, Darker @ clr, FontSize -> Scaled[fs]], 
       (1 + val) #, {0, -off 1.5}, - off Cross @ #],
     Polygon[Join[seg, tr @ Reverse[seg]]] }] &;
```

***Examples:***

Inputs from OP:

```
el = {"str4" -> "scst", "ma15" -> "srtl", "ma15" -> "shot", "ma15" -> "str4", 
   "ma15" -> "ma8", "ma15" -> "str3", "sfin" -> "shot", "sfin" -> "ma6"};

community = {{"ma15", "srtl", "ma8", "str3"}, {"shot", "sfin", 
    "ma6"}, {"str4", "scst"}};

valueAdded = {"str4" -> 12, "scst" -> 34, "ma15" -> 51, "srtl" -> 80, 
   "shot" -> 45, "ma8" -> 68, "str3" -> 34, "sfin" -> 56, "ma6" -> 73};
```

Rules for styling and labeling:

```
vA = Normalize[Association @ valueAdded, Max];

groupColors = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Subdivide[-1 + Length @ community];

clrRules = Join @@ 
   MapThread[(x |-> Blend[{#, White}, x]) /@ Normalize[#2, Total] &]@
    {groupColors, Query[#] @ vA & /@ community};

lblRules = AssociationThread[Join @@ community, Join @@ community];
```

With these inputs and sorted vertex list

```
vertexlist = Join @@ community;

gap = .2;

vertexCoordinates = TakeList[Rest @ 
   CirclePoints[{1, 0}, 1 + Length @ vertexlist], 
   Length /@ community]

barcount = Length[vertexlist];

Graph[vertexlist, el,
 VertexCoordinates -> Join @@ vertexCoordinates,
 EdgeShapeFunction -> poincareESF,
 VertexShapeFunction -> (VSF[][clrRules @ #2, lblRules @ #2, 
      vA @ #2, barcount, gap][##] &), 
 EdgeStyle -> {e_ :> 
    Directive[Thick, Opacity[1], Arrowheads[{{Large, .75}}], 
     clrRules[e[[1]]]]},
 ImageSize -> Large,
 PlotRange -> 2,
 ImagePadding -> 30,
 Prolog -> {AxisObject[
    Line[{{1, 0}, {2, 0}}], {0, Max @ Values @ valueAdded}, 
    LabelStyle -> 14, 
    AxisLabel -> Placed["Value Added", {1/2, {1/2, 3/2}}],
    TickLabelPositioning -> "Tip"],
   Thin, Gray, Circle[{0, 0}, 1 + #] & /@ Subdivide[5]}]
```

[image]

To introduce spaces between groups change `vertexCoordinates` and `barcount` as

```
vertexCoordinates = TakeList[Rest@
  CirclePoints[{1, 0}, 1 + Length[vertexlist] + 2 Length[community]], 
     2 + (Length /@ community)][[All, 2 ;; -2]];

barcount = Length[vertexlist] + 2 Length @ community;

gap = 0;
```

[image]

Replace `VSF[]` with `VSF["anystring"]` to get

[image]

Comment: TODO : add group labels

Comment: Thank you very much for the code! Since `vA` in graph is not defined in the code, I cannot get any graph picture as you present above. I tried different combinations of `valueAdded` variable to get the right `vA` but no success. Second, in community 3 in graph, `str4` bar should have the same color as `scst` (in my computer it looks they are of different colors). Currently, the colors of the bars in the 3rd community are different. Also, what do you mean with `VSF["anystring"]`?

Comment: I added the definition of `vA`. The reason for different colors within a group is that I blended the group color with `White` using the relative bar height as weight. By `VSF["anystring"]`, I meant any string except `"Bar"` (e.g, `VSF["blah"]`, `VSF["A"]`, ... `VSF["123"] ` gives the same result.

Comment: to get same color for bars in a group you can use `clrRules = Association[Join @@ Map[Thread]@Thread[community -> groupColors]]`

Comment: All works fine now. You have done much more than I could think of. I really appreciate very elegant pictures.

Comment: which function is for adjusting the height of bar charts? I just want to have a fixed height for all bar charts. Although I give a fixed vector like `ConstantArray[1, 20]` for example, I get very long bar charts. Thanks.