# How to plot a community structure with specific properties

Tags: graphs-and-networks, code-request, charts

[This code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/291828/60365) generates a community structure where each community is shown with a different color. The same color is used for bars within a community and outgoing edges from that community. I would like to have the same bar chart, with two modifications:

1. make all within-community edges transparent (very low opacity);
2. give a name for each community on the edge of the circle above the community bars.

The code in the link is too complex for me to understand!

**EDIT**

```
ClearAll[circleToCoords, poincareESF, VSF]

el = {"str4" -> "scst", "ma15" -> "srtl", "ma15" -> "shot", 
   "ma15" -> "str4", "ma15" -> "ma8", "ma15" -> "str3", 
   "sfin" -> "shot", "sfin" -> "ma6"};
community = {{"ma15", "srtl", "ma8", "str3"}, {"shot", "sfin", 
    "ma6"}, {"str4", "scst"}};
valueAdded = {"str4" -> 12, "scst" -> 34, "ma15" -> 51, "srtl" -> 80, 
   "shot" -> 45, "ma8" -> 68, "str3" -> 34, "sfin" -> 56, "ma6" -> 73};

circleToCoords[Circle[ctr_, rad_, {a1_, a2_}]] := 
  Module[{al = 
     Subdivide[a1, a2, 50]}, (ctr + rad {Cos[#1], Sin[#1]} &) /@ al];
poincareESF = Module[{}, GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart;
    ReplaceAll[c_Circle :> Arrow@circleToCoords[c]]@
     GraphComputation`GraphChartDump`geo[0.99 First@#, 0.99 Last@#, 
      "segment"]] &;
VSF[shape_ : "Bar"][clr_, lbl_, val_, vcount_, gap_ : .2, fs_ : .05] :=
   Module[{seg, angle = ArcTan @@ #, 
     width = (1 - gap) 2 Pi/(1 + vcount), 
     off = If[0 < ArcTan @@ # < Pi, 1, -1], 
     tr = If[shape == "Bar", TranslationTransform[val #], 
       Map[(1 + val) # &]]}, 
    seg = {Cos@#, Sin@#} & /@ 
      Subdivide[angle - width/2, angle + width/2, 50];
    {clr, 
     Text[Style[lbl, Darker@clr, 
       FontSize -> 
        Scaled[fs]], (1 + val) #, {0, -off 1.5}, -off Cross@#], 
     Polygon[Join[seg, tr@Reverse[seg]]]}] &;


vA = Normalize[Association@valueAdded, Max];
groupColors = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Subdivide[-1 + Length@community];
clrRules = 
  Join @@ MapThread[(x |-> Blend[{#, White}, x]) /@ 
       Normalize[#2, Total] &]@{groupColors, 
     Query[#]@vA & /@ community};
lblRules = AssociationThread[Join @@ community, Join @@ community];

vertexlist = Join @@ community;
gap = .2;
vertexCoordinates = 
 TakeList[Rest@CirclePoints[{1, 0}, 1 + Length@vertexlist], 
  Length /@ community]
barcount = Length[vertexlist];
Graph[vertexlist, el, VertexCoordinates -> Join @@ vertexCoordinates, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> poincareESF, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> (VSF[][clrRules@#2, lblRules@#2, vA@#2, 
      barcount, gap][##] &), 
 EdgeStyle -> {e_ :> 
    Directive[Thick, Opacity[1], Arrowheads[{{Large, .75}}], 
     clrRules[e[[1]]]]}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> 2, 
 ImagePadding -> 30, 
 Prolog -> {AxisObject[
    Line[{{1, 0}, {2, 0}}], {0, Max@Values@valueAdded}, 
    LabelStyle -> 14, 
    AxisLabel -> Placed["Value Added", {1/2, {1/2, 3/2}}], 
    TickLabelPositioning -> "Tip"], Thin, Gray, 
   Circle[{0, 0}, 1 + #] & /@ Subdivide[5]}]
```

generates:

[image]

Comment: At a minimum, please share some input data to play with.

Comment: @MarcoB: I will edit the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the following:

```
roundingText[text_,{a_, b_}, r_, ts_, style_:Black] :=
    Block[{txt, l, ang, st, ds},
        txt = Reverse@Characters[text];
        l = Length[txt];
        ds = ts;
        st = ((b - a) - l ts) / 2;
        If[st < 0, st = (b - a)*(0.02); ds = (b-a-st 2)/l];
        Table[
            ang = a + st + ds(i - 1);
            Text[Style[txt[[i]], style], r {Cos[ang],Sin[ang]}, Automatic, Through[{Cos,Sin}[ang - Pi/2]]]
        ,{i, 1, l}]
 ]

opfunc = 
  Function[{e}, 
   If[AnyTrue[community, SubsetQ[#, List @@ e] &], {Arrowheads[0], 
     Opacity[.2]}, {Arrowheads[{{Large, .75}}], Opacity[1]}]];

arcs = Mod[ArcTan @@@ (#[[{1, -1}]]), 2 Pi] & /@ vertexCoordinates;

comnames = {"community 1", "community 2", "community 3"};

groupbar = {{Opacity[.3], #1, 
      ChartElementData["Sector"][{#2, {2.45, 2.8}}]}, {Black, Thick, 
      Circle[{0, 0}, 2.45, #2]}} & @@@ Transpose[{groupColors, arcs}];

cnames = 
  Thread[roundingText[comnames, arcs, 2.6, .07, 
    Directive[20, GrayLevel[0], Thick]]];

Graph[vertexlist, el, VertexCoordinates -> Join @@ vertexCoordinates, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> poincareESF, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> (VSF[][clrRules@#2, lblRules@#2, vA@#2, 
      barcount, gap][##] &), 
 EdgeStyle -> {e_ :> 
    Directive[Thick, opfunc[e], 
     clrRules[e[[1]]]]}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> 3, 
 ImagePadding -> 30, 
 Prolog -> {AxisObject[
    Line[{{1, 0}, {2, 0}}], {0, Max@Values@valueAdded}, 
    LabelStyle -> 14, 
    AxisLabel -> Placed["Value Added", {1/2, {1/2, 3/2}}], 
    TickLabelPositioning -> "Tip"], Thin, Gray, 
   Circle[{0, 0}, 1 + #] & /@ Subdivide[5], groupbar, cnames}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code. It works very well! Which parameter is used to increase the size of the inner circle with edges?

Comment: Sorry for my correction request. Since the outgoing arrows originate from the same color community, there is no need to use arrow heads. I think that way the middle part of the figure will look cleaner.

Comment: @TugrulTemel do you just want to remove arrowheads for same community?

Comment: I found the way to remove arrow heads. My only request is to enlarge the inner circle of the figure so that the between-community edges are separated little bit. In my original graph, the density of the between-community edges is high.

Comment: @TugrulTemel It seems like it depends on many places in the code (vertex coordinates, shape functions, circles, etc). You better ask this to original author of plot.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help.